# Losing some events with ReadDirectoryChangesW on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, filesystems

I am using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to monitor a directory and its subdirectories for changes. These include both file and folder changes (creation, modification and deletion).

For my test, I copy a folder containing a couple of files, and a subdirectory containing 1 file, to the directory being watched (say, directory M). So, Folder A contains files X and Y, a subfolder B containing file Z.

As expected, I get multiple notifications for this action (copy folder, that is), which is expected...though I'd like to do without them as well.

The issue lies with inconsistency especially during a `delete` operation. When I delete folder A, I get notifications dealing with all other deletions, i.e., files X,Y subfolder B and Z within B, but I sometimes fail to receive a notification on deletion of folder A itself. This is very inconsistent, on some occasions I receive a notification on A being deleted, others not.
The same issue sometimes occurs on `copying` the folder as well.

I use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` asynchronously with an `Overlapped` and a buffer that is quite big enough.

Code -

Creating File handle :

```
std::wstring watchDirectory = std::wstring(m_DirectoryToWatch.begin(), m_DirectoryToWatch.end());
m_DirectoryHandle = CreateFile(watchDirectory.c_str(),
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                NULL);
m_Running = true;
m_Thread = std::thread(&DirWatch::watch, this);
```

Actual running thread :

```
 void DirWatch::watch()
    {
        while (m_Running.load())
        {
            std::vector<BYTE> byteBuf(12000);
            DWORD bytesReturned;
            OVERLAPPED overlapped = { 0 };
            overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

            ReadDirectoryChangesW(m_DirectoryHandle,
                &byteBuf[0], byteBuf.size(),
                TRUE,
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME,
                &bytesReturned,
                &overlapped,
                NULL);

            GetOverlappedResult(m_DirectoryHandle, &overlapped, &bytesReturned, TRUE);

            FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *>(&byteBuf[0]);
            do
            {
                std::wstring str(fni->FileName, fni->FileNameLength / sizeof(wchar_t));
                using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
                std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

                //use converter (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
                std::string filenameStr = converter.to_bytes(str);

                m_Callback(filenameStr, FileAction(fni->Action));

                fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)((BYTE*)(fni) + fni->NextEntryOffset);
            } while (fni->NextEntryOffset != 0);
        }
    }
```

Output -

```
Created: TestDirectoryFolder   //Copied folder to directory being watched
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder   // Finished copying

Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt    // Delete operation on TestDirectoryFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder   // Got notification of TestDirectory folder actually being deleted

Created: TestDirectoryFolder   //Second test - start copying
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Created: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder  //Finished copying

Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText.txt   //Starting deletion on TestDirectoryFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\TestText1.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder\TestText2.txt
Modified: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder
Removed: TestDirectoryFolder\SecondTestFolder //This is the last. No notification received about actual deletion of TestDirectoryFolder
```

I imagined it could be an issue with the `buffer` overflowing, but the size of the buffer is quite adequate, and it would not explain the inconsistency with the same deletion operation on same folder structure.

**UPDATE** - I am not sure if it has to do something with the latency, some events getting lost while I'm converting and printing string? I have noticed that if I do a "del" on the folder, the deletion message for `TestFolder` - outermost folder being deleted is generally received. But if I do a `shift + DEL`, waiting for user input to confirm deletion, then the last folder deletion notification isn't generally received.

This is on `Visual Studio 2015` with `Windows 10, v. 1607`

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Either `Del` or `Shift + Del`, I can receive the `FILE_ACTION_REMOVED` event when the outermost folder is being removing. So do you delete these file and folder one by one or directly delete the outermost folder?

Comment: I directly delete the outermost folder. I sometimes miss the deletion notification for the outermost folder. With `del` I seem to get it most of the times but with `Shift+DEL`, hardly at all.

Comment: I create a demo based on your code but I can only receive the outermost folder delete event. No other folder and files delete event. So I ask for you a complete demo to reproduce.